# how to use variables for strings in autoconf:configure.ac

Tags: autotools, m4

How to use variables for messages inside configure.ac

```
if test "$foo" = "yes"; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([this string is being used in WARN as well as ERROR])
else
    AC_MSG_WARN([this string is being used in WARN as well as ERROR])
fi
```

It would make sense to define the string *"this string is being used in WARN as well as ERROR" in a variable* and then use that variable in both **AC_MSG_WARN** and **AC_MSG_ERROR**. What is the best way to do that ?

In addition to that, does m4 has any macro which can replace this entire if else by taking string and $foo as argument ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
msg="this string is being used in WARN as well as ERROR"
if test "$foo" = "yes"; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([$msg])
else
    AC_MSG_WARN([$msg])
fi
```

> In addition to that, does m4 has any macro which can replace this entire if else by taking string and $foo as argument ?

If you write one, it will. :-).  The if-else isn't in m4, it's in the output of m4, the `configure` shell script.  Something like:

```
AC_DEFUN([AX_TEST_FOO], [
    pushdef([MSG],$1)
    pushdef([FOO],$2)
    AS_IF([test $FOO = yes], [AC_MSG_ERROR([$MSG])], [AC_MSG_WARN([$MSG])])
    popdef([FOO])
    popdef([MSG])
])
```

called like:

```
AX_TEST_FOO(["this string is being used in WARN as well as ERROR"], [$foo])
```

should be close.  I didn't try it.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the solution but seems there is some trivial mistake here somewhere. For me AC_MSG_WARN is always executed even if second argument is "yes".

Comment: test "$FOO" = "yes" seems to fail even if echo $FOO results in yes.

Comment: Removed the quotes from around $FOO.